# Congratulations to those whose hard work have paid off

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement

Should it be have/has paid off in the above sentence? What is the reasoning for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the subject of the subordinate clause is *hard work* (uncountable), you need *has*, not *have*:

> Congratulations to those whose hard work has paid off.